# Create HTML on Specific Time

Tags: vb.net, datetime, time

If have the following Code:

```
Public Shared Function GetNextWeekDay() As Date
    Dim value As Date = Date.Now
    Do
        value = value.AddDays(1)
    Loop While (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) Or (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    Return value
End Function


Public Shared Function DPLoadData() As String
    Dim s As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder("<head><meta http-equiv=""content-type"" content=""text/html;charset=utf-8"" /><META HTTP-EQUIV=""REFRESH"" CONTENT=""900"">")
    s.Append("<style type=""text/css"" media=""all""> body{font-family: Arial;}h4{font-size: 10pt;font-weight: bold;white-space: nowrap;margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;}")
    s.Append("th{font-size: 9pt;font-weight: normal;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;}td{font-size: 9pt;}.content td{border: solid 1px #dadada;}")
    s.Append(".content th {border: solid 1px #dadada;background-image: url(""tbl_header_row_bg.gif""); background-repeat: repeat-x; white-space: nowrap;}</style></head>")


  s.Append("<h3>" & "Daily Plan" & "</h3>")
        Dim strCurrDay As String = ""
        s.Append("<h5>" & strCurrDay & "</h5>")



    Dim CurrDateFirstDay As Date = GetNextWeekDay()
    strCurrDay = FormatDateTime(CurrDateFirstDay, DateFormat.LongDate)
    s.Append("<h5>" & strCurrDay & "</h5>")
    s.Append(LoadDataGroupByDate(CurrDateFirstDay))

    Return s.ToString()

End Function
```

The function DPLoadData generates an HTML file with a table and fills it with bookings.  Currently, the HTML file displays the bookings of tomorrow (e.g. if today is Monday, it displays the bookings for Tuesday and if today is Friday, it displays the bookings for Monday).

What i need is that the HMTL file gets generated at 5 p.m. For Example: If today is Monday, then the HTML file should be generated Monday at 5  p.m and should display the bookings for Tuesday until  Tuesday 5 p.m and Tuesday at 5 p.m the file should be generated for wednesday and should display the bookings for wednesday until wednesday 5 p.m, and so on.

How can i do that? Please help.

My Solution:

```
 Public Shared Function GetNextWeekDay() As Date
    Dim value As Date = Date.Now
    Dim intHour As Integer
    Dim intMinute As Integer
    Dim intSecond As Integer


    intHour = 17
    intMinute = 0
    intSecond = 0

    Dim newdatetime As DateTime = New Date(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, intHour, intMinute, intSecond)

    If DateTime.Now < newdatetime Then

        If value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
            value = value.AddDays(2)
            Return value
        End If

        If value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
            value = value.AddDays(1)
            Return value
        End If

        Return value

    ElseIf DateTime.Now > newdatetime Then
        Do
            value = value.AddDays(1)
        Loop While (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) Or (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        Return value
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you are basically looking for a way to execute a program at a given time? If so, have a look at [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or the [Windows scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569), depending on the OS you are running this on.

---

Update: So basically you just need to compare the current time and check whether it is before 5pm. Then you should have a function which return the data from 5pm current day until 5pm tomorrow.

You might want to have a look at [this VB tutorial for DateTime](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/date-time-functions-visual-basic). Basically you need to compare the current time with a date time consisting of the current date at 5pm.

---

Update: Just extend your if condition to also check that today is not Saturday or Sunday. Here's a little code snippet I just whipped up. I am not really familiar with VB, so this might not be 100% correct, but I think you get the idea.

```
Public Function GetNextWeekDay() As Date
    Dim value As Date = Date.Now
    Dim intHour As Integer
    Dim intMinute As Integer
    Dim intSecond As Integer

    intHour = 17
    intMinute = 0
    intSecond = 0

    Dim newdatetime As DateTime = New Date(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, intHour, intMinute, intSecond)

    If value.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Saturday And value.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Sunday And DateTime.Now < newdatetime Then
        Return value.Date
    Else
        Do
            value = value.AddDays(1)
        Loop While (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) Or (value.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        Return value.Date
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Basically i do not execute a programm. Iam calling a link. If i click in the link, a html side opens which displays the bookings. So i want to check the time in my Code. If Monday 5 p.m, then display the bookings for tuesday until 5.pm. and so on

Comment: Thanks, that link you posted helped me a lot. But i have just one little Problem. In the If clause where DateTime.Now < newdatetime, i return only the value. Because if thats true he should only display the bookings of today. But if weekday = saturday then he should display the bookings of monday, like in the else clause. I tried, but dont have a solution right now

Comment: Yeah there is something wrong, if i try this, the Date which is returned is kind of strange

Comment: You'll need to elaborate. What does "strange" mean exactly?

Comment: the returned Date looks like: Monday, 1. Januar 0001

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce that error. I updated the code to only return the date portion and ran it on my machine. It works fine for me.

Comment: Thx for your help, i found a solution on my own(Updated my Question). But thanks again for the link you posted, that helped me alot!